# Python dictionary comprehension to contain list of items not found in another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

There is a list and a dictionary. If an item in the list is not present in the dictionary add the item to a new dictionary. Below is the for loop which I'm trying to convert to dictionary comprehension.

```
for i in range(1, len(list_a)):
    if dict_main.get(list_a,'') == '':
        dict_new[list_a[i]] = None
```

Dictionary comprehension method as follows

```
dict_new = {list_a[i] if dict_main.get(list_a[i], '') == '' else None: None for i in range(1, len(list_a))}
```

Comprehension works fine but it adds an extra (None, None) key value pair. If else is removed it throws 'else expected' error. Please guide me.

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking for. Could you be more precise?

Comment: The sentence which begins "When for loop ..." is almost impossible to parse.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I've edited to make it more readable. Can you kindly guide me on this please.

Comment: don't use dict or list as variable names (those are class names). An instance of list can't be a dict key. This should be failing with TypeError unhashable type 'list' Perhaps if you gave a sample input? [mcve]

Comment: do you want {i: None for i in l if i not in d} ? l is the list, d is the dict

Comment: @KennyOstrom Apologies! Edited the question.
And that's perfect it works like a charm. You made it look so simple. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in the code of your regular loop:

- list indices start at `0`, hence you should write `for i in range(0, len(list_a))` or you will miss the first element of the list.
- a probable typo: `dict_main.get(list_a,'')` should be `dict_main.get(list_a[i],'')`.
- what happens if you have a mapping `x: ''` in the dict? `dict_main.get(x, '')` returns `''` and the mapping `x: None` is added to `dict_new`. Use `x not in d` to check if the key `x` is not mapped to a value in `d`.
- not really an issue, but in Python you can write `for x in my_list` to iterate over the elements of a list if you don't need the index (if you need the index, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is useful).

The rule of thumb is: first, fix the regular loop and then create a list/dict comprehension. Here's the fixed regular loop:

```
for x list_a:
    if x not in dict_main:
        dict_new[x] = None
```

Hence the dict comprehension (given in comment by @Kenny Ostrom):

```
dict_new = {x: None for x in list_a if x not in dict_main}
```

If you really need to produce a dict whose values are `None`, you can use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) with a collection of keys:

```
dict_new = dict.fromkeys(x for x in list_a if x not in dict_main)
```

Or, maybe clearer:

```
dict_new = dict.fromkeys(set(list_a) - set(dict_main))
```

---

Your dict comprehension trial is not filtered (no `if` at the end). It creates `len(list_a)` keys in the target dictionary, all mapped to `None`. Those keys are the elements of the list if `dict_main.get(list_a[i], '') == ''` (element not in `dict_main` or mapped to `''`), else `None`.

If several elements of the list are keys of the `dict_main`, the mapping `None: None` is added once then overriden because the keys of a dictionary are unique. This is why you have one (and only one) extra `None: None` at the end of the dictionary as soon as you have at least one element in the list that is a key of `dict_main`.